# Deleting a column from non existing table (before SELECT is done...!)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following code, which basically join two big tables, and another small 'chromoName' table which is then being used for sorting purposes of everything. I also extract some data from one of the columns and split it over 3 columns to allow the sorting procedure. At the end of the day my table generates a few excessive columns that I would like to remove. In addition, I would like to save the output as a new TABLE in my db (using the "into MYNEWTABLE" command).  I would like to save the FINAL edition of my table AFTER all 'service columns' has been removed.

```
select*
--into patient_agk_p
from chromosomes  --join the 'chrom' tbl to the BIG tbl for sorting purposes! 
inner join
(
select split_part(s2, '-', 1)s3,*
from
(select split_part(id2, ':', 1)s1,split_part(id2, ':', 2) s2, * 
from 

---creating consolidate table!
(
select COALESCE(a.promoterid_agk_p_k4,b.promoterid_agk_p_k27ac)id2, *
from agk_p_K4 a full join agk_p_k27ac b
on a.promoterid_agk_p_k4=b.promoterid_agk_p_k27ac
order by id2
)t1
---finished creating consolidate table

)t2
) t3 on s1=chromosomes.chromname  --done join the 'chrom' tbl to the BIG tbl for sorting purposes! 
order by chronumber,cast(s3 as int) --sort it!
```

So somewhere here maybe - would it be possible to remove say, 3 or 4 of the columns, and THEN save everything into patient_agk_p ???

Comment: What do you mean by "*remove*" and by "*save*"?

Comment: Okay - so by save I mean: using the "into MYNEWTABLE" command. -please see the 2nd line in my code, just below the SELECT * i have 'into patient_agk_p' this command would store/save all the output of the SELECT procedure into a new currently-non-existing table "patient_agk_p". AS for "remove", I mean - ALTER TABLE patient_agk_p2 DROP COLUMN chromname; this for example would alow me to remove a column, but this command works well on an existing table(!)... I wish to remove/drop a column BEFORE I save/place it into a non-existing table. TNX

Comment: How about **not** creating columns you do not need?

Comment: I think you simply need to remove all the stars (*) from your queries. You are returning all of your columns from each query instead of specifying the exact ones you want.

Answer (score 1):

using * here includes all columns, just list the columns you want

```
select column1, column2, column3 -- replace with actual columns
--into patient_agk_p
from chromosomes  --join the 'chrom' tbl to the BIG tbl for sorting purposes! 
inner join
(
select split_part(s2, '-', 1)s3 -- ,* remove this if you have all the columns you need, or specify the ones you want.
from
(select split_part(id2, ':', 1)s1,split_part(id2, ':', 2) s2 -- ,* remove this if you have all the columns you need, or specify the ones you want.
from 

---creating consolidate table!
(
select COALESCE(a.promoterid_agk_p_k4,b.promoterid_agk_p_k27ac)id2 -- ,* remove this if you have all the columns you need, or specify the ones you want.
from agk_p_K4 a full join agk_p_k27ac b
on a.promoterid_agk_p_k4=b.promoterid_agk_p_k27ac
order by id2
)t1
---finished creating consolidate table

)t2
) t3 on s1=chromosomes.chromname  --done join the 'chrom' tbl to the BIG tbl for sorting purposes! 
order by chronumber,cast(s3 as int) --sort it!
```

By including the '*' on the end of each query, you are returning every column from all the tables being joined. This is extremely bad practice (especially combined with the SELECT INTO) because if any of the tables get modified in the future the results of your query will alter and it will difficult to know why because the fields are not explicitly listed.

Comment: I'm using * as I want to save myself time of denoting all 15 column names. As you see, I create a few columns to extract specific data from a string in one of my columns. These 'service' columns use for sorting my table. after sorting I want to remove them. Of course I could select only the columns that I wish to select but since there are 15 out of 18 that I actually need I thought to use * and to remove 3 'service columns' instead. Does anyone familiar with a procedure which may allow dropping of columns as part of a query? I dont want to use a separate query just for removing the columns.

Comment: @Roy I understand it may seem easier to use the * instead of listing the columns, as I say at the end of the post, this is bad practice and a maintenance nightmare, because if any of the tables add new fields in the future, then your queries will break unexpectedly and you will have to go back fix them all every time a column is added. I have seen this happen many times, and when you go back to fix it years later, you make mistakes, because you can't always remember clearly the original intent, or the change is done by somebody else and they have to try to understand what the intent was.

Comment: @Roy it is also potentially possible that if you upgrade your server at some stage it might return your fields in a different order, than what you currently get, which will also break your INSERT INTO.  Or worse still it might not break it, it might just put different values into compatible fields, which will mess up all your data.  Debugging and fixing this will take 100x longer than specifying the columns now.